# Local expression of a quasi projective variety under finite morphism

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, diophantine-geometry

I am studying the article [*Around the Chevalley-Weil Theorem*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.05664) by Zannier, Turchet and Corvaja and I am stuck in the following point: let $V$ and $W$ be two complex quasi-projective varieties and $\pi\colon W\rightarrow V$ a finite map. In Proposition 3.4 it says that locally one can consider $W$ defined in $V\times\mathbb{A}^1$ by a polynomial equation
$$
 y^d+a_1(x)y^{d-1}+...+a_d(x)=0
$$
with $a_i(x)\in\mathbb{C}[V]$ and $d=\deg \pi$. Why is it true? I know that $\dim V=\dim W$ because $\pi$ is finite and that an integral expression does exist because of finiteness of $\pi$ but I can't figure out this.

Comment: What you said is not always true: it would imply that every finite map is flat. In the situation in the paper, the fibers of $\pi$ have constant cardinality. This implies that the map is etale.

Comment: And how it implies the polynomial expression..?

Comment: This follows essentially by the definition of finiteness, since (assuming $V$, $W$ affine for the sake of simplicity) the pull-back $\pi^* \colon \mathcal{O}_V(V) \to \mathcal{O}_W(W)$ is an integral ring extension.